# Lighting get darker when texture is aplied

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Im using OpenGL ES 1.1 for iPhone.

I'm attempting to implement a skybox in my 3d world and started out by following one of Jeff Lamarches tutorials on creating textures. Heres the tutorial: iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html

Ive successfully added the image to my 3d world but am not sure why the lighting on the other shapes has changed so much.  I want the shapes to be the original color and have the image in the background.

Before:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojmb8793vj514h0/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-01%20at%205.34.44%20PM.png

After:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/8v6yvur8amgudia/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-01%20at%205.35.31%20PM.png

Heres the init OpenGL:

```
- (void)initOpenGLES1
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    // Enable lighting
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    // Turn the first light on
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    const GLfloat           lightAmbient[] =  {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
    const GLfloat           lightDiffuse[] =  {0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0}; 
    const GLfloat           matAmbient[] =    {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5};
    const GLfloat           matDiffuse[] =    {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}; 
    const GLfloat           matSpecular[] =   {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    const GLfloat           lightPosition[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0}; 
    const GLfloat           lightShininess =   100.0;

    //Configure OpenGL lighting
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, matAmbient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, matDiffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, matSpecular);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, lightShininess);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition); 

    // Define a cutoff angle
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 40.0);

    // Set the clear color
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0f);

    // Projection Matrix config
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    CGSize layerSize = self.view.layer.frame.size;

    // Swapped height and width for landscape mode
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)layerSize.height / (GLfloat)layerSize.width, 0.1f, 750.0f);

    [self initSkyBox];

    // Modelview Matrix config
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // This next line is not really needed as it is the default for OpenGL ES
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    // Enable depth testing
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
}
```

Heres the drawSkybox that gets called in the drawFrame method:

```
-(void)drawSkyBox
{
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    static const SSVertex3D vertices[] = {
        {-1.0,  1.0, -0.0},
        { 1.0,  1.0, -0.0},
        {-1.0, -1.0, -0.0},
        { 1.0, -1.0, -0.0}
    };

    static const SSVertex3D normals[] = {
        {0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
    };


    static const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
        0.0, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5,
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.5, 0.0
    };

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Heres the init Skybox:

```
-(void)initSkyBox
{
    // Turn necessary features on
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);

    // Bind the number of textures we need, in this case one.
    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]); // create a texture obj, give unique ID
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]); // load our new texture name into the current texture

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"space" ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSData *texData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:texData];

    GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 ); // times 4 because  will write one byte for rgb and alpha
    CGContextRef cgContext = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );

    // Flip the Y-axis
    CGContextTranslateCTM (cgContext, 0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM (cgContext, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    CGContextClearRect( cgContext, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
    CGContextDrawImage( cgContext, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), image.CGImage );

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

    CGContextRelease(cgContext);

    free(imageData);
    [image release];
    [texData release];
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, had to add glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) in order for the colors to be correct.

Comment: mark as correct so this question doesn't stay open..

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct like Jari mentioned. It's past the cooldown point of not being able to accept it.